# How to handle multiple flatMaps with one defaultOnEmpty handler in Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

How can I handle empty responses from multiple flatMap's with a single defaultOnEmpty?
Like I have the following chain. The defaultOnEmpty gets only triggered if the last flatMap returns an empty result, but I want to get it also triggerd when e.g. the first flatmap returns an empty result (and just skip the other flatMap's).

```
repository.findById(id)
  .flatMap(...)
  .flatMap(...)
  .flatMap(...)
  .defaultOnEmpty(0)
```

Comment: in the example you have given the `defaultIfEmpty` operator will be invoked if any of the `flapMaps` return an empty Mono. The code you have provided gives the functionality you desire.

Comment: I have no clue why it didn't worked yesterday but you are absolutely right. Thx.

Comment: no worries. Glad you got it sorted